# Объясните как из 12% годовых получается ставка дисконтирования 0.9489 %?

Tags: математика

Мне необходимо составить программу, которая по годовой ставке будет рассчитывать ставку и коэффициент дисконтирования

В сети очень много информации на эту тему, но у меня просьба - напишите мне формулу и рассчитайте по ней, чтобы из 12% годовых получалась ставка дисконтирования 0.9489 %

Т.е. я знаю исходные данные ( это 12 ) и знаю результат ( это 0.9489 ). Мне нужна формула

Comment: Более подробно задача и решение представлены у меня на гитхабе по адресу https://github.com/veretennikovalexey/Pikachu/blob/main/Untitled0.ipynb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Формула следующая: ((1 + годовая ставка / 100)^1/12 – 1) × 100. В примере годовая ставка 12%.

Итоговая формула: ((1 + 12 / 100)^(1/12) – 1) × 100 = 0,948879293

Comment: **WarLikeLaux**, спасибо, добрый человек :)

Comment: ещё сюда добавлю, что теперь мне стало наконец-то ясно, как рассчитать коэффициент дисконтирования из этого примера. Это `1 : ( 1 + 0.9489 : 100 )` или `https://yandex.ru/search/?text=1+%3A+(+1+%2B+0.9489+%3A+100+)&lr=10750` и получается в итоге `0,9906`

Comment: Итоговая формула для расчёта коэффициента дисконтирования = `1 : ( 1 + (  ( 1 + годовая ставка / 100) ^ ( 1/12 ) – 1 ) × 100 : 100 )`

Comment: `1 : ( 1 + ( ( 1 + 12 / 100 ) ^ ( 1/12 ) – 1 ) )`